# How to automatically add hibernate xml mapping file(hbm.xml) in IDEA?

Tags: hibernate

How to automatically add hibernate xml mapping file(hbm.xml) in IDEA ?

I can not find the menu 'Hibernate mappings' In the Persistence tool window.

Do I miss anything?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to Project Structure (`Ctrl+Alt+Shift+S` on my box) → Facets → Plus sign at the top of dialog → Hibernate → and select your cfg.xml file there. hbm.xml should connect to project automatically.

[Here](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/persistence-tool-window.html) you can find info about generating persistence mappings. Briefly: in persustence tolls window you can right-click your persistence unit ang there generate persistence mappings.

Comment: I meant how to add a mapping file to for a persistent class.

Comment: Do you mean geneate it?

Comment: Yes, i want to generate Hibernate XML mapping file(hbm.xml). And i am new to use IDEA while i can automatically generate the hbm.xml file using Eclipse.

Comment: Updated my answer with appropriate link.